# Error compiling a Swift file with SwiftForWindows

Tags: swift, windows, github, compiler-errors, compilation

I installed SwiftForWindows https://swiftforwindows.github.io/. When compiling a Swift file I get the following error message: C: \ Program Files \ Swift \ mingw64 \ bin \ ld: cannot open output file C: \ Program Files \ Swift \ RuntimeEnv \ Hello.exe: Permission denied

Question:
Does anyone know what I have to do to make it compile?

Answer (score 1):

if you try to run a swift program in windows OS.

1. Download and install VS Code -> [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)
2. Download and install Swift For Windows -> [SwiftForWindows](https://swiftforwindows.github.io/)
3. Open this path and check the file is available -> `C:\Swift\bin\bin`
4. Open Visual Studio Code and install two extension -> 1.Code Runner 2.swift-sfdc
   [Code Runner Iamage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2LUN.png) [swift-sfdc Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx7hD.png)
5. In the Visual Studio Code `File->Open Folder or Ctrl+o`  then select bin folder `C:\Swift\bin\bin`
6. in the VS Code create new swift file
   and write this code for testing...
   `
   import Swift

print("Wolverine")
`
7. right-click on you swift file and click Run Code

output Image -> [Output iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2rIQ.png)